# livewire dispatchBrowserEvent function does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am tring to show alert message of javascript through livewire component public function render() { $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('alert', ['type' => 'success', 'message' => 'User Created Successfully!']); }
I gives error Method App\Livewire\Alert::dispatchBrowserEvent does not exist.
In resources\views\components\layouts\app.blade.php @livewireScripts
doucment.addEventListener('alert', function() { alert('this is alert from component '); });

I try dispatchBrowserEvent in  fresh project also.

Answer (score 0):

just found that Livewire v3 removed emit and dispatchBrowserEvent in favor of using a single dispatch method

Answer (score 0):

since Livewire 3, the dispatchBrowserEvent method no longer exists, so you have to use the normal event handler and interpret it on the front end.

**Application example:**

Livewire component:

```
$this->dispatch('close-modal');
```

Blade file for livewire component:

```
<div x-data="{ showModal: false }" x-on:close-modal="showModal = false">
</div>
```

Follow this link to learn more

https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/events#events-in-alpine